# AutoHotKey: detect single key release in keycombo for Firefox

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

Trying to configure key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to behave as [tab switcher](http://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/showcase) in Firefox with the help of AutoHotKey:

```
#IfWinActive Showcase
    LAlt & Tab::Send {tab}
    GetKeyState, state, LAlt
    if state = U
        Send {enter}
```

Basically this prevents <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> from bringing up the ordinary window switcher of Windows and cycles through open tabs as <kbd>Tab</kbd> is being pushed. However, as i’m trying to simulate the behaviour of Windows’ window switcher, i also want this to bring up – `Send {enter}` – the last selected tab when <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> is *released.* And this i can’t seem to accomplish, as `GetKeyState` just won’t respond, even though `state` becomes `U`. How can key release be detected in this case?

**ADD:**

So i ended up with the following code, which for the dominant part does what i wanted:

```
    #IfWinActive ahk_exe firefox.exe  ; Alt+Tab to Windows
        LAlt & tab::
        Send {F10}  ; F10 brings up Showcase in my FF installation
        WinWaitActive Showcase
        GetKeyState, state, LAlt, P
            if state = U
                WinClose Showcase
        IfWinNotActive Showcase
            Send {LWin}
    #IfWinActive Showcase  ; Alt+Tab over Firefox’s tabs
        LAlt & tab::
        Send {tab}
        SetTimer, choice, -50
        return
        choice:  ; Thanks, @user3419297!
            KeyWait, LAlt, P
            IfWinActive Showcase
                Send {LAlt up} {space}
        return
    #IfWinActive ahk_exe firefox.exe  ; Win+Tab over Firefox’s tabs
        LWin::F10
    #IfWinActive Showcase  ; Win+Tab to Windows
        tab::return
        LWin & tab::
        WinClose Showcase
        WinWaitClose Showcase
        WinMinimize ahk_exe firefox.exe
        Send {LWin down} {tab} {LWin up}
    return
    ExitApp
```

This in fact simulates both <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ & <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> behaviour in Firefox, which i usually use in fullscreen mode:

- pushing <kbd>Tab</kbd> while holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> will cycle through open tabs the same way <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> cycles windows
- to get out of FF to Windows, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> are quickly pushed and released; this will bring up the Start Menu from where one can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> the normal way
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> work a bit differently in Windows, in the way that one don’t need to hold down <kbd>Win</kbd> for it to stay up, and (at least in Windows 10) one can’t cycle through windows with <kbd>Tab</kbd>; this is also simulated the same way here by pushing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (actually just <kbd>Win</kbd> is enough, but for consistency i press both); <kbd>Tab</kbd> is also blocked so it can’t cycle, to simulate the way real <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> works in Windows
- to get out of Firefox’s <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to Windows, the said combo is pushed once more – this will bring up the normal <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> of Windows 10; the taskbar can also be easily accessed this way

Since i didn’t know any AutoHotKey before, looking back this was probably a bit of an overkill task to start with. However, this did force me to *actually learn* how to programme in AHK, while dusting off my overall programming skill. And for that this has been great. I often found myself instinctively pushing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> inside Firefox to cycle through tabs as one would do with windows, only to be reminded that this in fact only works with windows in Windows. Until recently, that is :)

Comment: If you enable the option "[**Ctrl+Tab cycles through tabs in recently used order**](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/startup-home-page-tabs-download-settings#w_tabs)" you can use "Ctrl+Tab" as tab switcher.

Comment: Aye, `Ctrl`+`Tab` has been around for quite some time. Thank you very much for your answer; i have expanded the code and will be sharing it soon in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#IfWinActive Showcase

    LAlt & Tab:: 
        Send {Tab}
        SetTimer Send_Enter, -50
    return

#IfWinActive     ; turn off context sensitivity

Send_Enter:
    KeyWait, LAlt, L
    Send {Alt Up}{Enter}
return
```

Comment: Indeed it did, @[**ADD**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44412202/autohotkey-detect-single-key-release-in-keycombo-for-firefox/44412202#comment75859673_44412202)!